# Generating SOAP XML from POJO

Tags: java, xml, soap

Hello for loging and debuging purpose I need to store input POJO of spring bean in DB in SOAP XML form. Can you help me which library i can use and do you have some code examples how to create SOAP XML from POJO object. I try to use javax.xml.soap.* to generate SOAP Envelope, Header and Body, and JAXB for generating xml from POJO. javax.xml.soap.* works fine, but i have problem with namespaces in POJO xml. Is there way to generate namespaces automaticaly? For example...

My output without namespaces is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <z:getClientDetail xmlns:z="my.package">
    <client>
      <adresses>
        <city>Praha</city>
        <houseNumber>1455</houseNumber>
        <street>Hudeckova</street>
      </adresses>
      <adresses>
        <city>Brno</city>
        <houseNumber>44</houseNumber>
        <street>Tupolevova</street>
      </adresses>
      <firstName>Standa</firstName>
      <lastName>Vrana</lastName>
    </client>
 </z:getClientDetail>
```

But correct output with namespace is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <z:getClientDetail xmlns:z="my.package">
    <java:client xmlns:java="my.package.dto">
    <java:adresses>
      <java:city>Praha</city>
      <java:houseNumber>1455</houseNumber>
      <java:street>Hudeckova</street>
    </java:adresses>
    <java:adresses>
      <java:city>Brno</city>
      <java:houseNumber>44</houseNumber>
      <java:street>Tupolevova</street>
    </java:adresses>
    <java:firstName>Standa</firstName>
    <java:lastName>Vrana</lastName>
   </java:client>
  </z:getClientDetail>
```

Thanks P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package level annotation [`javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) to accomplish this. JAXB will then generate the XML from the pojo's in the annotated package in the given namespace.

If you would prefer you can also do this on a class-by-class basis using the [`javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation or on a field-by-field basis using the [`javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store data in DB in SOAP XML form?

And to create SOAP XML from POJO object, you can write manually all the static part and put all dynamic values from POJO like below.
Ex:

```
String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">  <soapenv:Header><tem:B2BCode>"+pojo.getPojoObject+"</tem:B2BCode></soapenv:Header></soapenv:Envelope>"
```